# In PHP, how do I check if a function exists?

Tags: php, function

How can I check if the function `my_function` already exists in PHP?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Using [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function_exists):

```
if(function_exists('my_function')){
    // my_function is defined
}
```

Comment: And if you want to check for methods on classes, most people will recommend method_exists but that detects protected/private methods which aren't externally accessible. In that case is_callable is a better option in general.

Comment: @CaseySoftware - For convenience, [here's the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) for ``is_callable``, as this answer was a top result on Google.

Comment: It's hilarious how semantic and extensive PHP's library is. "how can I tell if a function exists?" "`function_exists`"

Comment: how to check this function if exists? `$date = new DateTime(); $date->getTimestamp() ` ?

Comment: if(!function_exists('my_function')) { }

Answer (score 26):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

```
<?php
  if (!function_exists('myfunction')) {

     function myfunction()
     {
       //write function statements
     }

}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var_dump( get_defined_functions() );
```

DISPLAYS all existing functions

Answer (score 4):

And if `my_function` is in namespace:

```
namespace MyProject;

function my_function() {
    return 123;
}
```

You can check if it exists

```
function_exists( __NAMESPACE__ . '\my_function' );
```

in the same namespace or

```
function_exists( '\MyProject\my_function' );
```

outside of the namespace.

P.S. I know this is a very old question and PHP documentation improved a lot since then, but I believe people still taking a peek here, and this might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I want to point out what [kitchin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php#110163) has pointed out on php.net:

```
<?php
// This will print "foo defined"
if (function_exists('foo')) {
  print "foo defined";
} else {
  print "foo not defined";
}
//note even though the function is defined here, it previously was told to have already existed
function foo() {}
```

If you want to prevent a fatal error and define a function only if it has not been defined, you need to do the following:

```
<?php
// This will print "defining bar" and will define the function bar
if (function_exists('bar')) {
  print "bar defined";
} else {
  print "defining bar";
  function bar() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Checking Multiple function_exists**

```
$arrFun = array('fun1','fun2','fun3');
if(is_array($arrFun)){
  $arrMsg = array();
  foreach ($arrFun as $key => $value) {
    if(!function_exists($value)){
      $arrMsg[] = $value;
    }
  }
  foreach ($arrMsg as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$value} function does not exist <br/>";
  }
}
function fun1(){
}

Output

fun2 function does not exist 
fun3 function does not exist
```