# How to check if input is a callable construct or function?

Tags: php

This is not a duplicate of "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351835/in-php-how-do-i-check-if-a-function-exists".

- https://www.php.net/function_exists will fail if input is a language
  construct (e.g. https://www.php.net/empty).
- https://www.php.net/is_callable with `$syntax_only = true` will allow
  language constructs (e.g. `empty`), though it will also allow
  `random_function_that_does_not_exist`.

How do I check if input is callable, either as an existing function or a language construct that behaves like a function?

Comment: Since `empty` is, as you say, *not a function*, it's somewhat vague what you want to know. Why would you be trying to call language constructs using variable code snippets (which is typically not possible to begin with)?

Comment: you ask to see if something is a function, but complain aoubt function_exists that it will fail for something that is not a function?

Comment: The intent is to detect whether input callback (whether it is a function or a language construct) can be used to validate user input.

Comment: Please describe your real issue. Why do you want this?

Comment: `empty` should not be used on variables which you know exist in the first place, so it's a bad callback for validation. `boolval` (PHP 5.5) or simply a test for thruthiness does the same thing.

Comment: Guys I too an curious what the use case is for this. Regardless, I think it's a valid question. There are language constructs that _behave_ like functions and then there are actual functions, and it seems valid to ask how to tell if something is callable either way.

Comment: The question might be misleading. I suggest rephrasing to "How to check if input is callable construct?", unless someone suggests better title.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas There doesn't appear to be a built-in way to do this in PHP. I think it'll require looking at the constructs on http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php and manually searching that list along with function_exists(). Example function to follow (since I can't post an answer).

Comment: Not sure if it will help you, but you could try to make an array with desired language constructs (like `empty()`), then store them in an array together with the output of `get_defined_functions()`, and check the input with `in_array($needle, $haystack_with_functions)`.

Comment: `function canICall($function) {
 $callableConstructs = array("empty","unset","eval","array","exit","isset","list");
 return function_exists($function) || in_array($function, $callableConstructs);
}`

Comment: @jszobody I've considered this. It seemed *hackish*, in sense that you hard-code the list. Though, I could not find a variable that would list the reserved keywords. Even then, the list would not tell if the keyword can be called as a function.

Comment: Yes it's hackish. But without any built-in way to do this in PHP (that I can find) I don't think you have another option. Also, that list is supposed to _only_ the keywords that _can_ be called as functions (it's not complete, just an example).

Comment: @jszobody (In response to earlier comment) The problem is that `empty` does *not* behave like a regular function. Its syntax may be function-like, but it actually behaves more like an operator than a function. The behaviour has been made more function-like in PHP 5.5, but it's still not the same.

Comment: @deceze we all know it's not the same. =) but it can be called like a function, and that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @jszobody Well no, it *cannot*: `call_user_func('empty', $foo)`. How would you call `list` in this way?

Comment: @deceze we can go on all day about how it doesn't behave like functions in certain ways. I believe the OP is just looking to test whether you can call "X" like `X('someinput')`. And with `empty()` you can.

Comment: @jszobody It seems to me he's trying to do `$validation = 'empty'; if (function_exists($validation)) $validation($value);` Regardless of whether he can make `function_exists` work or not, `$validation($value)` simply does not work with language constructs, so the question seems to be moot.

Comment: He never said he's trying to use variable function calls. If he is, then I fully agree with you. It's a worthwhile point to make, when providing an answer to his question. Still a valid question.

Comment: @jszobody The question doesn't make sense any other way to me. Let's hope he's not looking at `eval`. :)

Comment: He may very well be looking at eval. In which case you and I both will yell at him and tell him it's almost always a bad idea. =)

Comment: @GajusKuizinas Doesn't look like this question is getting reopened. Suggestion for the future: state your use case. Let folks help you solve your real problem, even if it means approaching it differently.

Comment: I was actually looking to call function using `'empty'()` construct. Therefore, this inevitably calls to maintain a list of language constructs *and* their implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all kinds of potential problems with what you're asking. However if I understand you right, you simply want to know if `somename` can be called like `somename('someinput')`.

If that's true, then it appears you need to use a combination of `function_exists` and a manual lookup of language constructs from the [List of Keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Something like this perhaps:

```
function canICall($function) {
    $callableConstructs = array("empty","unset","eval","array","exit","isset","list");
    return function_exists($function) || in_array($function, $callableConstructs);
}
```

*That `$callableConstructs` array is not complete, look at the List of Keywords page to build it out.*

Yes it is hackish, but without a built-in way to do this in PHP I don't see another option.

**Note that just because you can *call* something like a function, does *not* make it a function, nor does it mean that it *behaves* like a function in other ways.**

You cannot call it dynamically:

```
$var = "empty";
$var('someinput'); // Does NOT work
```

Nor does this work:

```
call_user_func('empty', $foo);
```

You *could* use it in an `eval` call, but I hope you understand the huge list of reasons why that can be dangerous.

Comment: But the calling code would need to look like `if (canICall('empty')) empty($foo)` or `if (canICall($func) && $func == 'empty') empty($foo)`, so... what's the point?

Comment: "What's the point?" Again, we're back to his use case. Which we don't know do we? Just trying to answer the simple question...

Comment: And IMO the correct answer is to point out that the working of `function_exists` is correct for a reason... :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `empty` *always* exists and is a language construct which cannot be called using variable functions, it doubly makes no sense to want to use `function_exists` on it. Even if `function_exists` would work, it is not possible to write this code:

```
$func = 'empty';
if (function_exists($func)) {
    $func($var);
}
```

The only way to call `empty()` is to write it literally in your source code. You cannot call it using variable functions any more than you can do that with `list() =` or `/`.

The best you could do is:

```
if (function_exists('empty')) {
    empty($foo);
}
```

But because `empty` always exists, what's the point in testing for it?

If you want to make a validation rule, simply write your own function:

```
function isEmpty($value) {
    return !$value;
}

$rule = 'isEmpty';
```

This does exactly the same thing.

Or you make `empty` a special case in your rule execution:

```
function validate($rule, $value) {
    switch ($rule) {
        case 'empty' :
            return !$value;

        default :
            if (!function_exists($rule)) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("$rule does not exist");
            }
            return $rule($value);
    }
}
```